# Behavior mismatch in Full text search between SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

Initially we had SQL Server 2005 and then migrated to SQL Server 2012. Then there was an issue in Full Text Search in SQL Server 2012

The output (result set) of SQL Server 2005 & SQL Server 2012 was different. They are as below:

1. We have created a new table in sql server 2005 and 2012 with some of sample data which is identical on both environment (2005 and 2012)..
2. And we created fulltext search index in both tables.
3. Then we run the below mentioned query in both envoirnment tables and the result as below.

Table name: candidate_search_test 
candidate_search_test table having 11 records in the both environment (2005 and 2012).

```
    searchText  userid 
1   java-script 10001 
2   javascript  10002 
3   java script 10003 
4   java    10004 
5   script  10005 
6   vb-script   10006 
7   sql-script  10007 
8   vb  10008 
9   vbscript    10009 
10  sql 10010 
11  sqlscript   10011
```

```
SELECT searchText 
FROM candidate_search_test 
where CONTAINS(searchtext,'java-script')
```

Note:

In 2005 environment the query returns 3 records which includes the result of “java-script”,”javascript”,”java script”.

In 2012 environment the query returns 2 records which includes only the result of “java-script”,”java script”.

Comment: The first speculation is that the data is different.

Comment: It's just me or the OP forgot to post the output?

Comment: We edited with details in the question. Kindly view the same. The query is updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005 (from 2000 to 2008 R2) there was a [feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/200043) that ignored dashes `-` when using Full-Text search. Now it is *fixed*.